# Get access token foursquare in ruby

Tags: ruby, oauth, foursquare, access-token

I'm a beginner in ruby, I'm studying foursquare API. I have a request

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&oauth_token=QUWOWXK2YGKXI4KIJVXFKYIHZ0I1AKD2XV0GEPCF2F5NQ1E0&v=20131030
```

I don't know how to get oauth_token for that request. How can i do it? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [foursquare2 gem](https://github.com/mattmueller/foursquare2), or if you'd like something more educational, https://github.com/pierrevalade/foursquare-rails-examples

Comment: Can you explain for me what client_id and client_secret are ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at our getting started guide for the API, that should explain most of the questions you have about oauth_token, client_id, and client_secret. https://developer.foursquare.com/start. It doesn't seem like you've created an app yet on Foursquare, which you need to do so in order to work with the API.